# Unable to export 8.0.1 MySQL database using MySQL Workbench 8.0

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, mysql-workbench

I'm unable to export my 8.0.1 MySQL database using MySQL Workbench 8.0.  When I go to perform the export via the "Administration" table, with all the default settings (I didn't change anything anywhere, not even Advanced settings) I run into this error:

```
09:10:26 Dumping account (all tables)
Running: /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/MacOS/mysqldump --defaults-file="/var/folders/m2/y4sdt3ks3_x206vw2gv37pgc0000gp/T/tmptSYqBY/extraparams.cnf"  --user=root --host=account.biblebowl.org --protocol=tcp --port=4488 --default-character-set=utf8 --no-create-info=TRUE --skip-triggers "account"
mysqldump: Couldn't execute '/*!80000 SET SESSION information_schema_stats_expiry=0 */': Unknown system variable 'information_schema_stats_expiry' (1193)

Operation failed with exitcode 2
09:10:26 Export of /Users/me/dumps/Dump20190207.sql has finished with 1 errors
```

I could downgrade to a previous version Workbench, but I'd prefer to get this one working and I imagine other folks are going to run into this as well.  How can I get around this error and properly export my database?

Comment: MySQL server version?

Comment: Server version: `8.0.1`

Answer (score 1):

[information_schema_stats_expiry](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_information_schema_stats_expiry) was added in 8.0.3. Use the MySQL Workbench for 8.0.1. I hope you're upgrading to a stable version.

Comment: The first 'GA' version is 8.0.11.

Comment: I've tried using the latest stable.  Quite frankly I manage several different MySQL servers on different versions and am frustrated that my version of workbench matters.  I don't want to juggle several different versions of workbench depending on the server I'm connecting to.  I'm just going to use a different MySQL management tool.